# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

## SOLVED

Thanks to Predrag Maric I managed to find a bug which was that referencedColumnName was not referring to the right field. then I had to make the Table2 class implement the Serializable Interface and this made my test pass

Thanks for your help

## Question

How can I map Table3 in Hibernate?

[image]

**This is my attempt:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Table3")
public class Table3 implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="field1")
    private String field1;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="field2")
    private String field2;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Table2_id")
    private Table2 Table2_id ;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Table2_Table1_username")
    private Table2 Table2_Table1_username;
```

**The error is in my JUnit test:**

`Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`Table3`, CONSTRAINT`fk_Table3_Table2`FOREIGN KEY (`Table2_id`,`Table2_Table1_username`) REFERENCES`Table2`(`id`,`Table1_username`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`

**Constructor:**

```
Table3(String field1, String field2, Table2 table)
{
    this.field1 = field1;
    this.field2 = field2;
    this.Table2_id = table;
    this.Table2_Table1_username = table;
}
```

**JUnit Test**

```
@Before
    public void init() 
    {
        JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbc.execute("DELETE FROM Table3");
        jdbc.execute("DELETE FROM Table2");
        jdbc.execute("DELETE FROM Table1");
    }
 @Test
    public void testCreateMedia()
    {
        table1DAO.createTable(table1Object);
        table2DAO.createTable(table2Object);
        table3DAO.createTable(table3Object); //fails here
    }
```

Noted:
I am not using java naming convention for variables

Comment: Well, does it work? What's the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood `name` and `referencedColumnName` in `@JoinColumn`.

`name` is the name of the column in source (`Table3`) table which is a foreign key to target (`Table2`) table.

`referencedColumnName` is the name of the column in target table which is a primari key (`Table2.id`). This attribute can be omitted in most cases.

In your case, it should look like this

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="Table2_id")
private Table2 Table2_id ;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="Table2_Table1_username")
private Table2 Table2_Table1_username;
```

Comment: This has helped a bit but my problem is still there. Please see my updated question

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved my problem as explained above